# Calling function from a list of quoted lambda expressions

Tags: list, lambda, macros, common-lisp

If I have a list of lambda expressions like this:

```
CL-USER> (DEFPARAMETER list-of-lambda-exp '(#'(lambda (x) x) #'(lambda (x) (* x x))))
```

Then how do I funcall on an element of this list?

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
CL-USER> (funcall (FIRST list-of-lambda-exp) 2)
```

gives the error

```
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL) datum: #'(LAMBDA (X) X)>.
```

... which is consistent with the call to `functionp` on `(first list-of-lambda-exp)`. (The above is true even if I remove the `#'` in front of the lambda expressions.)

How do I change `(first list-of-lambda-exp)` into a function? I cannot seem to figure out how to write a macro that would do this either. I think I'm making a dumb mistake but can't figure a way out.

Comment: You quoted the list. That means it contains sublists that just happen to start with the symbol `LAMBDA`, not function objects. You need to use `LIST` instead of quote.

Comment: To elaborate on @jkiiski's point, the `'(#'(lambda (x) x) #'(lambda (x) (* x x))))` is the list `(quote ((function (lambda (x) x)) (function (lambda (x) (* x x)))))`.  That is, remember that `#'(lambda (x) ...)` is shorthand for `(function (lambda (x) ...)`. You can actually coerce the *list* `(lambda (x) ...)` into a function, so it'd be a bit easier if your original form were `'((lambda (x) ...) (lambda (x) ...))`, without the `function` part.

Comment: Thank you!! I can work with this. Out of curiosity: what if the list was in fact quoted?

Comment: @RanjitKumaresan The list is quoted, it's just that the lambda expressions are one level deeper than your code expects them to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of things happening here.  First, remember that **quote**, which can be abbreviated with **'** returns its argument unevaluated.  Then, remember that **#'** is shorthand for **function**.  That is, **#'(lambda (x) ...)** is shorthand for **(function (lambda (x) ...))**, not just a variant of the list **(lambda (x) ...)**.  Thus:

```
CL-USER> (quote ((function (lambda (x) x)) (function (lambda (x) (* x x)))))
;=> (#'(LAMBDA (X) X) #'(LAMBDA (X) (* X X)))
```

Thus, you can either go multiple levels into the list to get the actual lambda expression (just a list starting with **lambda**), which you can then [**coerce**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_coerce.htm) into a function that you can call:

```
CL-USER> (let ((fs '(#'(lambda (x) x) #'(lambda (x) (* x x)))))
           (list (funcall (coerce (second (first fs)) 'function) 42)
                 (funcall (coerce (second (second fs)) 'function) 8)))
;=> (42 64)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!!

Comment: It's also possible that doing `(list #'(lambda ...` instead of `'(#'(lambda....` would've been the better choice. I think you were intending to mention that, based on your "Thus, you can either...", but it looks as if that paragraph got missed out.